# need help for sql query on case

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

i had table as

```
s.no--------------Amount--------accCode-----discount-----status
  1-----------------20-------------2.1-------10.00------------yes
  2-----------------30-------------2.1-------6.00-------------yes
  3-----------------20-------------3.1-------10.00------------No
  4-----------------30-------------2.1-------10.00------------yes
  5-----------------40-------------3.1-------5.00-------------No
  6-----------------20-------------2.1-------10.00------------yes
```

i need to select all the row from the table with its values but i need to show the **discount amount 0.00** if its **status** is **No** Otherwise i need the same as in table. please could anybody help me on this. thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethnig like this?

```
SELECT
   sno, amount, acccode,
   CASE [status]
     WHEN 'No' THEN 0.0
     ELSE discount
   END AS 'discount' 
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Really thanks,  can i use * in select statement as i have many field.

Comment: @Dinupkandel: **NEVER** use `SELECT *` in production code - **NEVER EVER**

Answer (score 0):

```
case [status]
  when 'No' then 0
  else discount
end as discount
```